# Remove duplicate index value from first array, manipulate second as per first(at some specific conditions)

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is the tricky one :

please understand my scenario:

1. I have two array , both array will have equal length always.
2. I want remove duplicate value in first array and second array will be manipulated according first one.

like if i have array like :

```
var firstArr = [1,1,4,1,4,5]
var secArr = ['sagar', 'vilas', 'suraj', 'ganesh','more','abhi']


//I want below Output
//[1,4,5]  // this is firstArr after manipulation
//['sagar|vilas|ganesh','suraj|more',abhi] // this is secArr after manipulation

// here all duplicate values will be removed from first array 
// and at same index second array will be manipulated.
```

please check my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/abhilash503001/du4fe8ob/86/

Comment: why  `[1,4]` it is not `[1,4,5]` ? you want to keep duplicate values only in firstArr after manipulation ?

Comment: i am sorry i forget to edit. no dont want duplicate in first array, first array will have unique values

Comment: @Abhi, you mentioned **both array will have equal length always.**. Your sample code doesn't agree with that.

Comment: @Udo E, both array have equal length(6).

Comment: ok, i see the update now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I did it.

You first group the texts into arrays and then join them together.

```js
var index_array = [1,1,4,1,4,5]
var text_array = ['sagar', 'vilas', 'suraj', 'ganesh','more','abhi'];
var manipulated_text_array = [];
var manipulated_index_array = [];

var groups = {};

for (let index in index_array) {
    if (groups[index_array[index]] == undefined) {
        groups[index_array[index]] = [];
    } 

    groups[index_array[index]].push(text_array[index]); 
}

for (let index in groups) {
    manipulated_text_array.push(groups[index].join("|"));   
}

manipulated_index_array = Object.keys(groups).map(x => parseInt(x));

console.log("texts", manipulated_text_array);
console.log("indexes", manipulated_index_array);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Map` and `reduce`

- First loop through the first array and map it values as key and take the values from second array's respective index as key
- Now you have loop on the map's entries take the key's will be your unique firstArr and to get desired value for second arr you need to join values by `|`

```js
var firstArray = [1,1,4,1,4,5]
var secArr = ['sagar', 'vilas', 'suraj', 'ganesh','more','abhi']

let op = firstArray.reduce((op,inp,index) => {
  if(op.has(inp)){
    let val = op.get(inp)
    val.push(secArr[index])
    op.set(inp, val)
  } else {
    op.set(inp,[secArr[index]])
  }
  return op
},new Map())

let {firstArr, secondArr} = [...op.entries()].reduce((op,[first,second])=>{
  op.firstArr.push(first)
  op.secondArr.push(second.join('|'))
  return op
},{firstArr:[],secondArr:[]})

console.log(firstArr)
console.log(secondArr)
```